# Create modal form dialog in function

Tags: jquery

My app works with many modal form dialogs, i want to create modal form dialog by call a function, but i get error when i click OK button on dialog "i.apply is not a function". My code below

html:

```
<div id="dlg_srch_acnt">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="dtl_acnt_srch" style=" padding-bottom:0px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Account name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Script

```
function init_dlg(id, autoOpen, height, width, modal, fn_button1)
            {
                id.dialog({
                    autoOpen:autoOpen,
                    height:height,
                    width:width,
                    modal:modal,
                    buttons:{
                        'OK':fn_button1,
                    },
                    close:fn_close
                });
            }



function fn_ok()
            {
                $('#parnt_acnt').val(acnt_name);
                $('#dlg_srch_acnt').('close');
            }

init_dlg($('#dlg_srch_acnt'), false, '440', '480', true, 'fn_ok()');
```

Comment: Sorry for being "late to the party", but perhaps my answer will help with any lingering questions.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your `$('#dlg_srch_acnt').('close');` should be `$('#dlg_srch_acnt').dialog('close');`

And pass function `fn_ok` name in argument not `fn_ok()` because that is executed value of it.

```
init_dlg($('#dlg_srch_acnt'), false, '440', '480', true, 'fn_ok');
```

And what is `acnt_name` in your `fn_ok` function? Either define it (before using it) or pass a string, not a variable name.

Comment: I corrected $('#dlg_srch_acnt').dialog('close'); but nothing change

Comment: @ Rajat Singhal : acnt_name is input field. It's OK. Can you test fn_ok with only alert command : alert("OK");. I think this problem from function call a function

Comment: @ Rajat Singhal : Can you help me?

Comment: Dude first remove `()` from fn_ok() call..as I answered..and give some string instead of acnt_name in fn_ok function..

Comment: Good answer +1 (no quotes when passing the function name, though)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#dlg_srch_acnt')` as you are passing a jquery object to your function. so you need to wrap your id with jquery like this

```
function init_dlg(id, autoOpen, height, width, modal, fn_button1)
            {
                $(id).dialog({ // Jquery wrapping should be done . 
                    autoOpen:autoOpen,
                    height:height,
                    width:width,
                    modal:modal,
                    buttons:{
                        'OK':fn_button1,
                    },
                    close:fn_close
                });
            }
```

Comment: why? wouldn't `id` be a `jQuery` object already in that context?

Comment: init_dlg($('#dlg_srch_acnt'), false, '440', '480', true, 'fn_ok()'); i passed id was $('#dlg_srch_acnt')

Answer (score 0):

How about maybe removing the comma after fn_button1 since you only have one button

```
buttons:{
          'OK':fn_button1
        },
```

Comment: Coma after fn_button1 is syntax of Dialog, it separates buttons and close

Answer (score 0):

There were several things wrong here.

<kbd>[**Working jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/P9LB3/)</kbd>

.1. As Rajat pointed out, `$('#dlg_srch_acnt').('close');` should be `$('#dlg_srch_acnt').dialog('close');`

.2. Rajat *almost* correct regarding passing function name. Should be like this (no quotes):
`init_dlg($('#dlg_srch_acnt'), false, '440', '480', true, fn_ok);`

.3. When referencing external functions from inside the jQUI dialog object, you must still wrap them in function blocks:

```
    buttons: {
        'OK': function(){
            fn_button1();
        }
    },
    close: function(){
        fn_close();
    }
```

*Note that you did not have fn_close defined in the original post*

Here is complete code, with a few added bits to show it working (in particular, watch for BOB to change to JANE upon dlg close):

**HTML:**

```
<input id="parnt_acnt" type="text" value="bob" />
<div id="dlg_srch_acnt">
    <p>Inside the dialog</p>
</div>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
var acnt_name = "jane";

function init_dlg (id, autoOpen, height, width, modal, fn_button1 ) {
    id.dialog({
        autoOpen: autoOpen,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        modal: modal,
        buttons: {
            'OK': function(){
                fn_button1();
            }
        },
        close: function(){
            fn_close();
        }
    });
}

init_dlg( $('#dlg_srch_acnt'), false, '440', '480', true, fn_ok );

function fn_ok() {
    $('#parnt_acnt').val(acnt_name);
    $('#dlg_srch_acnt').dialog('close');
}

function fn_close() {
    $('#dlg_srch_acnt').dialog('close');
    alert('Close fn accessed');
}
```

<kbd>[**Working jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/P9LB3/)</kbd>